# Notation for random variable times indicator function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation, random-variables

Is the following notation of common use? For a random variable $X$ and an event $A$, $X\mathbb{1}_A$ is denoted as $(X|A)$? I find it in the following paper (the random variable is $\pi_i$ and the event $\{\pi_i\geq\tau_i\}$ there): https://cris.maastrichtuniversity.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/63013641/CFHOV18MOR_final.pdf
in the problem description at page 3. The definition is not given, so I am not sure if this is what is intended (which seems to me, from the context) or something else...
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: This notation is confusing to me, as the $\mid$ symbol is far more commonly used to denote conditioning...

Comment: I know it does not make any sense, I do not know whether they are referring to a 'conditional random variable' (whatever that means, in statistics and applied branches this is actually a common abuse) or to an actual random variable, since they say 'random variable' one should assume the latter and interpret it perhaps as an indicator being there, but maybe the use 'random variable' for 'conditional random variable', doubling down on the abuse... I hate it when people get so sloppy that you cannot even understand the model description properly...